# bulk insert into a table from a tab-delimited text file with additional column not existed in the file

Tags: sql, sql-server

the table that im trying to insert into has an additional first column which is id that doesnt exist in the file. Below is my attempt trying to insert the record from the file(with header row) while inserting to the additional column but im getting repeated syntax error on the command

```
SELECT  @fileName=[FileName], 
            @email=[Email],
            @CustomerId=ImportBy,
            @fullPath = 'D:test.txt'
    FROM [dbo].[Log_Import] 
    WHERE INTID = @intId      
                            
    SET @command = 'BULK INSERT [dbo].[ProcessTesting] SELECT ' + CAST(@intID AS VARCHAR(50)) +', * FROM ''' + @fullPath + ''' WITH ( FIELDTERMINATOR =''\t'', FIRSTROW = 1 )'
    EXEC(@command)
```

Comment: *" im getting repeated syntax error on the command"* And what is that error..?

Comment: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.
Incorrect syntax near 'D:test.txt'.
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

Comment: If you have a look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) you'll see that after the table you are bulk inserting into the next keyword should be `FROM`, not `SELECT`.

Comment: i see but how can i make the statement correct?

Comment: When bulk inserting, the source and destination objects need to have the same definition. It appears here they do not. Most likely you'll need to `BULK INSERT` into a staging table first, and then transform the data from the staging table to the production table. In essence, instead of of ETL, you're doing ELT.

Comment: i am fairly new to stored procedure. can u further explain it to me? thank you

Comment: There's no Stored Procedures in the above though, What do Stored Procedures have to do with the above?

Comment: Or you can add a default constraint on the target, and use a format file with only the other columns specified

Comment: this is a section of the stored procedure that i took out to test individually for functionality @Larnu

Comment: @Charlieface can u explain further? I am not very familiar with sql and had to learn it online

Comment: You would need to `EXEC` the following `'ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ProcessTesting] ADD CONSTRAINT DF_ProcessTesting_ID DEFAULT ' + CAST(@intID AS VARCHAR(50)) + ' FOR ID'` then bulk insert using the correct syntax, ignoring that column, then drop the constraint. Another option is you can use `OPENROWSET(BULK`

Answer (score 1):

You could use `OPENROWSET(BULK` to insert with a custom `INSERT...SELECT` statement.

I strongly suggest you use a format file.

```sql
SELECT  @fileName=[FileName], 
            @email=[Email],
            @CustomerId=ImportBy,
            @fullPath = 'D:test.txt'
    FROM [dbo].[Log_Import] 
    WHERE INTID = @intId      
                            
SET @command = '
INSERT [dbo].[ProcessTesting] (ID, OtherColumnsHere)
SELECT 
  ' + CAST(@intID AS VARCHAR(50)) +',
  OtherColumnsHere
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK ' + QUOTENAME(@fullPath, '''') + ', FORMATFILE = ''YourFormatFile'', FIRSTROW = 1 ) r;
';

EXEC sp_executesql @command;
```

> Note use of `QUOTENAME` to escape the file name properly

Comment: what if i only want to use the text file that i uploaded? since this is an operation where it started from a file upload from customer and the stored procedure reading the file and insert it into the table

Comment: I have no idea what you mean? Please be clearer. "the text file that i uploaded" as opposed to what other text file? "it started from a file upload from customer" how is that relevant?

Comment: it means other than the text file upload it is all automated so do i have to create the format file manually?

Comment: Once you've created a format file, you could use the same one every time (assuming it's always the same format in the text file)

Comment: what are the alternatives to this approach? i would like to keep everything in the code

Comment: You could manage without a format file if it's not too complex.

Comment: yes it is not complex. just a normal day to day transaction kind of insertion. What do i need to change from here?